# Download a file from a website that uses doPost request Java

Tags: java, download

I'm new to java. I'm trying to write a code that download file from these web sites https://servizissiir.regione.emilia-romagna.it/FlussiMTS/ and https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo.
in both web sites, before starting download, the user has to set to parameters.

For the second one I use successfully this code because I can insert parameters in the URL .

```
public class Downloader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String remoteFile = "https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo/Bologna/2021/Gennaio?format=csv";
        String localFile = "src/Bologna.csv";

        try {
            FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(remoteFile), new File(localFile), 20000, 20000);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

But with the first one I can't use the URL. The URL I see when I start download is https://servizissiir.regione.emilia-romagna.it/FlussiMTS/MobiliterServlet
So I think parameters are sent to a doPost servlet.

If I put this URL in the previous code I obtain a damaged rar archive in my local folder.

Comment: The first URL is just an HTML page, not a CSV. There is no way for you to know what HTTP method or "servlet method" handles the request to get a CSV file unless you have the source code

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution

`

```
 public static void PostRequest(String url, int i) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(rc).build();
    HttpPost httpPost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters;
    httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("forward", "esportaReportCSV"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("yearPromptName", "AnnoMese:"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("esportaReportCSV", ""));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tipoIntervallo", "M"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("AnnoMese:", "202108"));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("prompt", "Nessuno"));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters, "UTF-8"));
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);    
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        if (response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("application/zip")) {
            String name = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition").getValue();
            String fileName = name.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "$1");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path/" + fileName);
            entity.writeTo(fos);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Download success!");
        } else if (!response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("application/zip") && i < 10) {
            i++;
            PostRequest(url, i);
        } else if (!response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("application/zip") && i == 10) {
            System.out.println("Download failed!");
        }
    }
    client.close();
}

public static void GetRequest(String url, int i) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    RequestConfig rc = RequestConfig.custom().setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD).build();
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(rc).build();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    httpGet.setHeader("User-Agent", "User-Agent");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        if (response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("text/csv")) {
            String name = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition").getValue();
            String fileName = name.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "$1");
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("path/" + fileName);
            entity.writeTo(fos);
            fos.close();
            System.out.println("Download success!");
        } else if (response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("text/html") && i < 10) {
            i++;
            GetRequest(url, i);
        } else if (response.getEntity().getContentType().getValue().trim().equals("text/html") && i == 10) {
            System.out.println("Download failed!");
        }
    }
    client.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    PostRequest("https://servizissiir.regione.emilia-romagna.it/FlussiMTS/MobiliterServlet" , 1);
    GetRequest("https://www.ilmeteo.it/portale/archivio-meteo/Bondeno/2020/Agosto?format=csv", 1);
    }
```

`

I also wrote the HTTP Get solution

to work the code needs the following jar files:
httpclient-4.5.6.jar
httpcore-4.4.10.jar
commons-codec-1.10.jar
commons-logging-1.2.jar

parameters and the http method can be found through a browser's developer tools